# Information about current user in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get facebook userid of the users currently logged in.
I used this below piece of code ang got error "Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"

```
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '226668060741665',
  'secret' => 'secret key',
));

$rr=$facebook->getAccessToken();

$params = array(
'access_token' => $rr,
'installed' => 'true',
'permissions' => 'read_stream,publish_stream'
);
$eded=$facebook->api("/me/", "GET", $params);
```

I tried to use `Facebook::getLoginStatusUrl()` but didnt get what it return.
If i can use above function, please tell me how to get id of current logged in user and How can I use return value of `Facebook::getLoginStatusUrl()`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use recent [PHP-SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and read documentation which shows exactly how to [authenticate](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) the user and [get his details](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#personalization).

Exact answer you need already present in [PHP-SDK examples](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)

You may also refer to question [Get ID from Facebook PHP SDK](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8718401/get-id-from-facebook-php-sdk) which have answer to your question too.

Comment: Did you followed last link in my answer? Just do it!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. You generate an url: `$next_url = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();`
2. redirect the user to this url: `header('Location: '.$next_url);`
3. the user will be returned by FB with session information about the login status
4. the SDK will parse the returned info
5. use `$facebook->getUser();` to get the access_token and userid (if logged in)

So far so good. The only problem is, this function (point 4) is broken since the transition to oAuth2.0 by Facebook API, see also this bug report: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295348980494364

The returned $_GET['session'] is useless in the new oAuth2.0 SDK, it was used in the old PHP-SDK v2 (current is 3.1.1).

So please let FB know that you have the same issue by adding a reproduction.

Cheers!