# Know the facebook id of current logged user

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Information about current user in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738943/information-about-current-user-in-facebook)

How to know facebook id of current logge user,
getLoginStatusUrl will provide url, but i want details of user who have currently logged ..
How to get this using facebook php sdk.
Please specify the function and parameter to be used.

Comment: You just posting same question as one previous just without the code sample... Refer to answers on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8718401/get-id-from-facebook-php-sdk and http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8738943/imformation-about-current-user-in-facebook

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP:

```
$facebook_user_id = $facebook->getUser();
```

Using javascript SDK:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') { 
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID; // this is the ID of the user

  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    //but not connected to the app
  } else {
    // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```